# bash wildcard expansion even if quoted

Tags: bash, wildcards

The current directory contains file1 and file2.
How do you explain this output:

```
[root@server test]# command='*';
[root@server test]# echo $command
file1 file2
```

Why is * expanded? I expect it not to be because it's quoted.

Comment: Because `$command` is unquoted. Try `"$command"`, and you'll get `*`.

Comment: Right... but I don't really understand why it has to be quoted...

Comment: Actually I think Stephane's question is a more appropriate duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/237982

Comment: When the command is interpreted, it undergoes a few [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions). Relevant in this case: parameter expansion (turns `$command` into `*`), and then filename expansion (turns `*` into filenames in the current directory). Quoting suppresses that second expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command='*'` does indeed as you expect set the value of `$command` to a literal `*`.  However, when you run `echo $command`, the value of `$command` is expanded to `*`, making your command `echo *`.  The wildcard is then expanded as per usual.  To prevent this, quote the parameter you are giving to `echo`:

```
$ v='*'
$ echo "$v"
*
```